# Get if following page

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get if user following or no the page. I'm try like this:

```
    class Page extends Model
    {

        public function get_following()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Followers::class, 'user_id')->where('type', '=', 1)->where('follower_id', auth()->user()->id)->Select('id');
        }
}
```

But this return null.

dd($page)

```
    Page {#303 ▼
#attributes: array:9 [▼
    "id" => 1
]
      #relations: array:3 [▼
        "ptag" => Tag {#307 ▶}
        "get_following" => null
```

Table followers:

```
followers.user_id = (pages.id), follower_id = (auth user), type = (1)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

change select to `->value('id')`

```
public function get_following()
 {
   return $this->belongsTo(Followers::class, 'user_id')->where('type', '=', 1)->where('follower_id', auth()->user()->id)->value('id');
 }
```

Comment: Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on integer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public function get_following()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Followers::class, 'user_id')
                ->where('type', '=', 1)
                ->where('follower_id', auth()->id())
                ->pluck('id');   
}
```

Comment: BadMethodCallException
Method addEagerConstraints does not exist.

Comment: The name is Followers

Comment: okay then make sure you have a column named follower_id, maybe it should be just id . @ValterSousaCardoso

Answer (score 0):

```
public function get_following()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Followers', 'user_id')
                ->where('type', 1)
                ->where('follower_id', Auth::user()->id())
                ->pluck('id');   
}
```

Comment: BadMethodCallException
Method addEagerConstraints does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made